# How to construct objects of nested class templates with the same argument?

Tags: c++, constructor, class-template

How to construct objects of nested class templates with the same argument?

How to write the constructor to make following code compile?

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    T v;

    S(T v) : v{v} {}
};

int main() {
    S<int>{0};          // OK.
    S<S<int>>{0};       // OK.
    S<S<S<int>>>{0};    // Compilation error. I want this to compile.
    S<S<S<S<int>>>>{0}; // Compilation error. I want this to compile.
    // ...              //                    I want more...
}
```

The Compilation errors:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'S<S<S<int> > >'
no matching constructor for initialization of 'S<S<S<S<int> > > >'
```

Comment: You have to write it as `S<S<S<int>>>{S<int>{0}};`... etc.

Comment: Or, provide converting constructor from `int`.

Comment: @songyuanyao This is not so elegant.

Comment: @DanielLangr There will be two same constructor `S(int)`.

Comment: @chaosink Then, remove the original constructor. Or, provide a [specialization for `int` template argument](https://godbolt.org/z/dnrakF).

Comment: @chaosink Only one impclit conversion is allowed, so it's impossible to convert `0` to `S<>` and then to `S<S<>>` and then ... once.

Comment: @DanielLangr That works! But I don't want the constructor be specific to `int`. I want to write `S<float>(1.1f)` also.

Comment: @chaosink Then, make your additional constructor templated: https://godbolt.org/z/W5u7Xt.

Comment: Please, edit your question and write the error you get.  Is it a compilation error? if so? what error do you get?

Comment: @LuisColorado Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a second converting constructor. If you want to support any type, just make this constructor templated:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
   T v;

   S(T v) : v{v} {}

   template <typename U>
   S(U v) : v{v} {}
};
```

This work as follows:

```
   S<int>{0};          
   S<S<int>>{0};       
   S<S<S<int>>>{0};    
   S<S<S<S<int>>>>{0}; 

   S<double>{0.0};
   S<S<double>>{0.0};       
   S<S<S<double>>>{0.0};    
   S<S<S<S<double>>>>{0.0};
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/NKEGRz

Note that at the very bottom level, both constructors are applicable, but the non-templated one will be selected according to the C++ overloading rules.